# subscription profiles not supported

Tags: paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-subscriptions

PayPal subscription was created from PayPal website standard and the subscriber ID starts with "I". When i call `getrecurringpaymentsprofiledetails` its displaying below error `subscription profiles not supported`. Let me know any other way to fetch the subscription details created using PayPal standard without using IPN.

Comment: The *subscription ID* starts with 'I'.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn’t away without relying on IPN and then running a query against your own database.  Those API’s are mainly for recurring payments (those created via Express Checkout Recurring Payments with the `CreateRecurringPayments` API call), not the Website Payments Standard subscriptions that you are setting up.  There are a few things you can do with the recurring API’s against the subscriptions but not all of the functionality is supported for subscriptions.  This would be one of them.

Comment: Any other API is available to fetch the subscription details in website payments standard?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting it through this way:

```
let options = {
 method: 'post', headers: {'content-type':'application/json','Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':true},
 auth:{'username':process.env.PAYPALID,'password':process.env.PAYPALPASSWORD},
 url: 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
 data: 'grant_type=client_credentials',
}
axios(options).then((response)=>{let paypaltoken=response.data.access_token
axios.get('https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/'+agreementid+'/transactions?start_date=2018-01-01&end_date=2019-07-07', { headers: { 'Authorization':'Bearer '+paypaltoken, 'Content-Type':'application/json', } })
.then((transaction)=>{console.log(transaction.data)})
.catch(err => {console.error(err);console.log('err: '+JSON.stringify(err)); res.send (err) })
})
.catch(err => {console.error(err);console.log('err: '+JSON.stringify(err)); res.send (err) })
```

then if you get just the transaction.data, you will get a series of transaction objects, whose `status` is == `Completed` only if the transaction went ok, that is, it has not been cancelled, so just check the last for plan controlling purposes.
When `status` is == `Canceled` you know the agreement is not active anymore.

Another way to do it if you receive monthly payments is to set the first date to 2 months from "now()" and the second date to "now()". If you get no transactions then the status could be not active, but double-check: there is the random possibility there could have been some credit card problem. In that case I suppose `status` could be == to `delayed` or something else, but I had no possibilities to test it so I don't know. The idea came from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080544/subscription-profiles-not-supported-by-recurring-payment-apis-while-updating-pla) and the relative second answer which deserves my gratitude.

Note that according to your case you may need to add `'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':true` in the headers instead of other `withCredentials: true` or similar in the request.